# selecting from drop down menu other than Select in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to select an option from a drop down menu. Select is not working.
I have used below Python code to click on the drop down button.

```
inputElement=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#WIN_0_777031003 > a").click()
```

I have used below code to click on an option from the list. But its giving error

`NoneType object has no attribute 'find_element_by_tag_name'`

```
for option in inputElement.find_element_by_tag_name('option'):

if option.text == "New":

 option.click()

 break
```

[Drop down image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz5DD.png)

Comment: Also tried gettext(). But no gain. I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: Can you please post html here.

Comment: <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d menu" style="top:0px; left:340px; width:24px; height:24px;">
<img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/mt_sprites.gif" alt="Menu for Status" title="">
</a>

Comment: This is HTML for the drop down button. If you see the image attached, space beside drop down button is empty and you have to click the drop down button to bring the options and select from them. If i use SELECT, it gives error the select does not work on text.

Comment: you have provided partial html which is button link.I need complete html code to resolve.Could you please share the url you are trying if possible or share full html code.